# Local Variable Not Initialized

Tags: java, swing

So I am trying to figure out this assignment and I can not move on in it until I figure this out.

Im a super newb here this is my first java experience, so heads up there. I'm going to attempt to explain this best as I can.

This is how my code is right now

```
public static void confirmation() throws Exception
{
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("order.txt");
    BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(fr);
    String name, returning, type, qty, total;
    String nameOutputMsg, customerName, returnOutputMsg, customerReturn, typeOutputMsg, typeReturn, qtyOutputMsg, qtyReturn, totalOutputMsg, totalCost, greetingOutputMsg;


    name = br.readLine();
    returning = br.readLine();
    type = br.readLine();
    qty = br.readLine();
    total = br.readLine();

    // build output strings
            nameOutputMsg     = "Welcome " + customerName + ".\n\n";
            returnOutputMsg   = "Your return customer status is " + customerReturn + ".\n";
            typeOutputMsg = "Your choice of stocking is " + typeReturn + ".\n";
            qtyOutputMsg ="You are buying " + qtyReturn + " stockings.\n";
            totalOutputMsg = "The total for your order today is $" + totalCost + ".\n";
            greetingOutputMsg = "Thank you for visiting ThinkGeek!" + "\n\n"
                              + "You should recieve a reciept of your purchase in your email soon!\n";
            //display total cost

            outputMsg = nameOutputMsg + returnOutputMsg + typeOutputMsg + qtyOutputMsg + totalOutputMsg + greetingOutputMsg; //add outputs
    //display total cost


}
```

I'm getting one error and one warning. The warning is " outputMsg can not be resolved to a variable. So I've tried several things, first thought was hey I need to add that to my string list at the top. So I did, now that error has gone away, BUT 5 more have appeared and one warning. The errors are now "the local variable customerName may not have been initialized" This error is repeated for customerReturn, typeReturn, qtyReturn, totalCost. And the warning is resource leak: 'br' is never closed. SO at this point I change the code to look like this:

```
public static void confirmation() throws Exception
{
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("order.txt");
    BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(fr);
    String name, returning, type, qty, total;
    String nameOutputMsg, returnOutputMsg, typeOutputMsg, qtyOutputMsg, totalOutputMsg, greetingOutputMsg, outputMsg;
    String customerName = null; 
    String customerReturn = null;
    String typeReturn = null; 
    String qtyReturn = null;
    String totalCost = null;



    name = br.readLine();
    returning = br.readLine();
    type = br.readLine();
    qty = br.readLine();
    total = br.readLine();

    // build output strings
            nameOutputMsg     = "Welcome " + customerName + ".\n\n";
            returnOutputMsg   = "Your return customer status is " + customerReturn + ".\n";
            typeOutputMsg = "Your choice of stocking is " + typeReturn + ".\n";
            qtyOutputMsg ="You are buying " + qtyReturn + " stockings.\n";
            totalOutputMsg = "The total for your order today is $" + totalCost + ".\n";
            greetingOutputMsg = "Thank you for visiting ThinkGeek!" + "\n\n"
                              + "You should recieve a reciept of your purchase in your email soon!\n";
            //display total cost

            outputMsg = nameOutputMsg + returnOutputMsg + typeOutputMsg + qtyOutputMsg + totalOutputMsg + greetingOutputMsg; //add outputs
    //display total cost


}
```

NOW i have more warnings that appeared

The BR one is still there, then these have been added : "the value of the locl variable outputMsg is not used" and 
"Multiple Markers at this line
-The value of the local variable name is not used" and this repears for name, qty, total, returning and type. Here is my complete code if needed

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.*;

public class ThinkGeekPhase1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // declare variables
        String openingMsg, nameInputMsg, customerName, returnInputMsg, customerReturn, 
                typeInputMsg, typeReturn, qtyInputMsg, qtyReturn;

        double cost = 9.99;
        double salesTaxRate = .075;
        double totalCost = 0;
        int qty;

        try
        {

        // display opening message
        openingMsg = "*** Welcome to ThinkGeek Online Ordering System ***\n"
                   + "                     It's a great day to purchase fun geeky items!!";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, openingMsg);

        // get required input using dialogs
        nameInputMsg   = "Please enter your name: ";
        customerName   = getStringInput(nameInputMsg);
        returnInputMsg = "Are you a returning customer (yes or no)? ";
        customerReturn = getStringInput(returnInputMsg);
        typeInputMsg = "What type of stocking would you like? (Alien, Cat, Bunny, Devil)";
        typeReturn = getStringInput(typeInputMsg);
        qtyInputMsg = "How many stockings would you like?";
        qtyReturn = getStringInput(qtyInputMsg);

        qty = Integer.parseInt(qtyReturn);

        totalCost = totalCost(qty, cost, salesTaxRate);

        //write data 
        writeOrderFile(customerName, customerReturn, typeReturn, qty, totalCost);
        //read data
        confirmation();

        System.exit(0);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    } 

    public static String getStringInput(String prompt) throws Exception
    {
        String inputValue;
        int count =1;
        do
        {
            inputValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(prompt);
             count++;
            if (inputValue == null) //User Pressed Cancel Button.
            {
                throw new Exception("Cancel Button Pressed, Program closing");
            }
            if (inputValue.equals(""))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Form was blank, try again.");
            }

        } while (inputValue.equals("")  && count < 4);
            if (inputValue.equals(""))
            {
                throw new Exception("Form was blank for three attempts.");

            }
        return inputValue;
    }
     public static double totalCost(int number, double cost, double salesTaxRate)
    {
        double total = 0;

        total = (number * cost) * (salesTaxRate + 1);

        return total;
    }
    public static void writeOrderFile(String name, String returning, String type, int qty, double total) throws Exception
    {
        File file = new File("order.txt");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);

        pw.println(name);
        pw.println(returning);
        pw.println(type);
        pw.println(qty);
        pw.println(total);

        pw.close();
    }
    public static void confirmation() throws Exception
    {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("order.txt");
        BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(fr);
        String name, returning, type, qty, total;
        String nameOutputMsg, returnOutputMsg, typeOutputMsg, qtyOutputMsg, totalOutputMsg, greetingOutputMsg, outputMsg;
        String customerName = null; 
        String customerReturn = null;
        String typeReturn = null; 
        String qtyReturn = null;
        String totalCost = null;



        name = br.readLine();
        returning = br.readLine();
        type = br.readLine();
        qty = br.readLine();
        total = br.readLine();

        // build output strings
                nameOutputMsg     = "Welcome " + customerName + ".\n\n";
                returnOutputMsg   = "Your return customer status is " + customerReturn + ".\n";
                typeOutputMsg = "Your choice of stocking is " + typeReturn + ".\n";
                qtyOutputMsg ="You are buying " + qtyReturn + " stockings.\n";
                totalOutputMsg = "The total for your order today is $" + totalCost + ".\n";
                greetingOutputMsg = "Thank you for visiting ThinkGeek!" + "\n\n"
                                  + "You should recieve a reciept of your purchase in your email soon!\n";
                //display total cost

                outputMsg = nameOutputMsg + returnOutputMsg + typeOutputMsg + qtyOutputMsg + totalOutputMsg + greetingOutputMsg; //add outputs
        //display total cost


    }
}
```

When I run the program, it terminates right after asking how many stockings I want.

Ok I edited to this

```
public static void confirmation() throws Exception
    {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("order.txt");
        BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(fr);
        String nameOutputMsg, returnOutputMsg, typeOutputMsg, qtyOutputMsg, totalOutputMsg, greetingOutputMsg, outputMsg;
        String customerName = null; 
        String customerReturn = null;
        String typeReturn = null; 
        String qtyReturn = null;
        String totalCost = null;



        nameOutputMsg = br.readLine();
        returnOutputMsg = br.readLine();
        typeOutputMsg = br.readLine();
        qtyOutputMsg = br.readLine();
        totalOutputMsg = br.readLine();
        outputMsg =br.readLine();

        // build output strings
                nameOutputMsg     = "Welcome " + customerName + ".\n\n";
                returnOutputMsg   = "Your return customer status is " + customerReturn + ".\n";
                typeOutputMsg = "Your choice of stocking is " + typeReturn + ".\n";
                qtyOutputMsg ="You are buying " + qtyReturn + " stockings.\n";
                totalOutputMsg = "The total for your order today is $" + totalCost + ".\n";
                greetingOutputMsg = "Thank you for visiting ThinkGeek!" + "\n\n"
                                  + "You should recieve a reciept of your purchase in your email soon!\n";
                //display total cost

                outputMsg = nameOutputMsg + returnOutputMsg + typeOutputMsg + qtyOutputMsg + totalOutputMsg + greetingOutputMsg; //add outputs
        //display total cost


    }
```

It's still saying I'm not using outputMsg though and I"m not sure why, cause It's used right there at then end?

Comment: so ... what exactly is the code you have now?

Comment: IMHO "the value of the locl variable outputMsg is not used" says it all. You can remove the variable and the assigment and your programm will still do the same.

Comment: Please format your code. Do so be selecting the code and clicking the curly brackets icon in the editor.

Comment: Seems to me that last code 'll compile and run just fine.

Comment: You should really think about starting off with a smaller project. Those errors, individually, would be pretty easy to figure out on your own, and you'd learn how to deal with them in the future.

Comment: You haven't declated `outputMsg`.

Comment: the last code posted is my current code

Comment: Resueman, I wish I could unfortunately this is the code I have to work with for my class, it's a beginners programming class, and they kinda threw us into the middle of things.

Comment: This seems a little extreme for I/O practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting things incorrectly.  It says that the value of your variables are never used because you set them and then never touch them again.  Also, `customerName`, `customerReturn`, `typeReturn`, etc. are not the variables you set the values to.  You need to use `name`, `type`, etc.

Basically, make sure you are using the correct variables in your output messages and that should get rid of your uninitialized warnings.

Your "never used" warnings are because you are setting values to variables and then not using the variables for anything else.

EDIT:
You are now overwriting your `OutputMsg` strings which makes the br.readLine() useless.

You should do the following:

```
    name = br.readLine();
    customerReturn = br.readLine();
    type = br.readLine();
    qty = br.readLine();
    total = br.readLine();


    // build output strings
            nameOutputMsg     = "Welcome " + name + ".\n\n";
            returnOutputMsg   = "Your return customer status is " + customerReturn + ".\n";
            typeOutputMsg = "Your choice of stocking is " + type + ".\n";
            qtyOutputMsg ="You are buying " + qty + " stockings.\n";
            totalOutputMsg = "The total for your order today is $" + total + ".\n";
            greetingOutputMsg = "Thank you for visiting ThinkGeek!" + "\n\n"
                              + "You should recieve a reciept of your purchase in your email soon!\n";
            //display total cost

            outputMsg = nameOutputMsg + returnOutputMsg + typeOutputMsg + qtyOutputMsg + totalOutputMsg + greetingOutputMsg; //add outputs 
    System.out.println(outputMsg);
```

Comment: You're welcome.  Be sure to mark my answer as the accepted answer if this is what you were looking for!

Answer (score 0):

> And the warning is resource leak: 'br' is never closed.

See this [article](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=8) about closing streams to remove memory/resource leeks.

> "the value of the locl variable outputMsg is not used" and "Multiple
>   Markers at this line -The value of the local variable name is not
>   used" and this repears for name, qty, total, returning and type.

You are assigning an object to those variables, but never using the variables for anything. The compiler is alerting you that you could simply remove them from the code and it would not change the functionality.

Comment: And look at the argument you've passed into that function:  ``writeOrderFile(customerName, customerReturn, typeReturn, qty, totalCost);``. Don't confuse the parameter names in the method's signature with the actual variables you're passing into the function. You could change the method sig to be ``writeOrderFile(String hat, String cat, String rat, int bat, double mat) throws Exception`` and it would not effect the args being passed in.

Comment: Ok I fixed the long error, but I'm still not sure why it's saying I don't use the outputMsg?

Comment: Because you're *not using it*.  If you deleted the line``outputMsg = nameOutputMsg + returnOutputMsg + typeOutputMsg + qtyOutputMsg + totalOutputMsg + greetingOutputMsg; //add outputs`` from your code, its functionality would not change. You've simply assigned ``outputMsg`` a String, but aren't doing anything with it; its not used in further executions.

Comment: I tried to delete it completely from the code, ultimately I want the file reader to work, It creates the file and I get a txt document called order but I can't get it to read it, and make the order confirmation to appear. I thought the outputmsg would do that. When I deleted it though it made the not being used message appear for all the other strings, and I assume that's because the output msg is using them when it's there but nothing is when it's gone...But I'm not sure how to fix it I guess. I was using a JOptionPane.showMessageDialog but now they want us to use this file reader...